# Get past 6 months MONTH in ref to TODAY

Tags: vba

Need help in displaying 6 month past month in refrence to todays date. E.g current month is June. below is the code, but is giving the as 1,I need to get January.

```
MsgBox ("Cheques would be checked for issue Month of  " & (Month(Date)-5))
```

Comment: Unrelated, but notice that whitespace between the `MsgBox` function call and the opening `(` parenthese: that's the VBE telling you that the parens are superfluous and that whatever is inside them is going to be evaluated as a value and passed `ByVal`. Not a problem *here/now*, but can definitely bite you in the rear end in other circumstances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 MsgBox ("your date is " & DateAdd("m", -6, Date()))
```

Comment: Thanks Doug, small change made....thanks again  MsgBox ("your date is " & FORMAT(DateAdd("m", -6, Date()),"MMMM"))